# Resolve "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined" error in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, require

I am trying to set up a basic contact form using SengGrid and I keep getting a "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined" error.

I have this code in a script tag in the head of the html page.

```
    var sendgrid = require('sendgrid')(username,pass);
```

I have looked at requirejs, but I am not sure why I am getting this error. Could someone explain to me how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you really using node.js? This code is supposed to be added in your JavaScript server's code, not in the HTML page.

Comment: Node.js is not in the browser. If you want to use requirejs in the browser you will need to use a script tag to load it in.

Answer (score 10):

`require()` is not built into the browser.

So when you say that "I have this code in a script tag in the head of the html page." that would explain why the symbol `require` is not defined when the script runs.  If you want to use `require()` in the browser, then you need to first use a script tag to load a library that defines the require function and supports the `require()` type functionality and make sure that is successfully loaded before you try to use `require()`.  [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) is one such library that you could use.

`require()` is built into node.js on the server so it is always available there.

Comment: what do I need to do to have require() in angularjs?

Comment: @cfl - please re-read the middle paragraph of my answer.  I tell you right there what you can use if you want `require()` like functionality in a browser.  Here's an article about it: http://www.sitepoint.com/using-requirejs-angularjs-applications/

Answer (score 4):

Basically you need to transform your source code for the browser, replacing require calls with the actual module code.
Take a look at these utilities:

- http://browserify.org/ - it does exactly the transformation you need
- https://webpack.github.io/ - a more complicated web packaging framework, with lots of other useful features.